# Rename Files - Bulk - Recursive - User Interactive

Tags: powershell

I am trying to build a script to rename files using PowerShell.  I'm close.  Can't figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Right now I get the following on the line after selecting my folder path and entering in the input requested:

```
cmdlet Rename-Item at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path:
```

Here is my script:

```
$i = 1
$FolderBrowser = new-object -com Shell.Application
$folder = $FolderBrowser.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder", 0, "C:\temp\renamefiles\files")
#ShowNewFolderButton = $false

if ($folder.Self.Path -ne "") {write-host "You selected " $folder.Self.Path}

$inputname = Read-Host 'Enter Name Here'

ls $folder.Self.Path | %{Rename-Item -New ('$inputname"+"{0}"+".pdf' -f $i++)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
ls $folder.Self.Path | %{Rename-Item -New ('$inputname"+"{0}"+".pdf' -f $i++)}
```

to either

```
ls $folder.Self.Path | Rename-Item -NewName {"$inputname{0}.pdf" -f $script:i++}
```

or

```
ls $folder.Self.Path | ForEach-Object {
  Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ("$inputname{0}.pdf" -f $i++)
}
```

With the first variant (`Rename-Item` reading directly from the pipeline without a loop) you need to use `$script:i` inside the scriptblock, because it's a different scope from the rest of the script.

Comment: This is getting closer.  Now I get the following:         Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Comment: Wait.  I see its naming only 1 of the files in the directory I choose.  I think you missed this part of my code:  $inputname = Read-Host 'Enter Name Here'.  What I need it to do is use the name provided by the user.

Comment: @TomWildt Yeah, you need double quotes around the format string to have the variable expanded. There was also a scoping issue with the first variant. See updated answer.

Comment: thank you sir!  I also added a underscore by using:  "${inputname}_{0}.pdf"

Answer (score 1):

What about this as a template:

```
Get-ChildItem *.doc | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.doc$','.old' }
```

What exactly do you want to rename?